# While doing a header file exercise in C++, met "ERROR"

Tags: c++

```
/* Header.h */
// filename : Testcpp41.h

namespace ProcCom {
    void SimpleFunc(void);
}

namespace BestCom {
    void SimpleFunc(void);
    void PrettyFunc(void);
}



/* Source1.cpp */
// filename : cpp_41_2.cpp 

#include <iostream>
#include "Testcpp41.h"

using namespace std;

void BestCom::SimpleFunc(void) {
    cout << "BestCom is defined." <<"\n";
    PrettyFunc();
    ProcCom::SimpleFunc();
}

void BestCom::PrettyFunc()
{
    cout << "Pretty !! " << "\n";    
}
void ProcCom::SimpleFunc(void) {
    cout << "ProcCom is defined" <<"\n";
}


/* Source2.cpp */
// filename : cpp_41_3.cpp
#include "Testcpp41.h"

int main(){
    BestCom::SimpleFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

I thought that the first source file need to be compiled.

So I am trying to compile it.

And then, I got the error as below.

I searched the issues about "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64."

But I don't know & figure out what the solution is.

If you already knew, or experienced it before, Please let me know what you already knew.

Error :

```
jinhojeon@jinui-Macmini cpp % g++ cpp_41_2.cpp -o cpp_41_2
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: how do you compile and link the code?

Comment: To perform compile only (produce object file, no linking to executable binary), add `-c` option to `g++`.

Comment: Your program doesn't have a main function. "But," you say, "it's in Source2.cpp!" yeah but you're probably not compiling Source2.cpp into your program.

Comment: Try `g++ -c cpp_41_2.cpp -o cpp_41_2.o` (mind the `-c`)

Comment: or try `g++ cpp_41_2.cpp cpp_41_3.cpp -o myExec`, but you will need `#include` guards in your header file ... <O/T> but very odd file names IMO,, and what are Header.h, Source1.cpp and Source2.cpp? Stale comments? Other project files?

Comment: Right as Stale comments said @yano

Comment: @YSC It worked. Since, whether there exists an error or not, just complied. That's why "source2.cpp" couldn't.

Comment: @user253751, I thought that the logic : make a header file(function), define them in the first source file, and then complie the first. And then, complie the second source file. As 463035818_is_not_a_number said, that the problem is "link" with header and source file. But I don't know why it makes an error. I just did what the book said. what is the matter with Arm64?(My question)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Please read above. And My question is the latter(how to link those files and solve the error messages.)

Comment: @MikeCAT can make "cpp_41_2.o" file. but #include, the object file? happend as below <U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><E0><U+0005><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><D8><U+000F><U+0000><U+0000><U+0003><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0010><U+0019><U+0000><U+0000>7<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>2<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0018><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+000B><U+0000><U+0000><U+0003><U+000B><U+0000>...

Comment: @JeonJINo No, you need to **compile without linking** each source file (using `-c` flag) and then link the two together. Or, you can compile and link all at once by telling the compiler both source file names. Otherwise, it tries to make a program using just one source file, and that doesn't work because there isn't a main function.

Comment: g++ cpp_41_2.cpp cpp_41_3.cpp -o cpp_41_  I GOT That thank you all :D:D:D:D:D @yano You knew !!

Comment: Thank you all my teachers.